# Game-Development questions - where?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked a question relating to computer game-design before, and someone hinted such questions are not allowed on SU.  Is there a comparable site QA resource for game development?

Comment: If it's a programming question you can ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: On the night of the summer solstice of leap years, you will see an eagle flying to the mountains. Follow her and she will lead you to the hut of an old man who always wears an axe. Get there before sunrise and ask him. He will answer.

Answer (score 14):

If you have questions about coding computer games you can ask them on [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: or here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, if you have a programming-related question, Stack Overflow is a fine place to ask those questions.

However, questions about general game design that *do not* involve programming belong elsewhere. There are a few sites in the [Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) that would be suitable for asking these questions.

[Game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) explicitly supports questions of this topic, and might be the first site you want to try

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted (because of the link to a SE site?) - game design questions are indeed not allowed on SO as they are not programming related. This is stuff like "If Strength modifies attack power by 0.5 per point, should I somehow throttle the gain if Dexterity is much lower than strength so that people don't just push their strength on every level-up".

Comment: @Michael: It was partly my fault in the original answer for not explicitly separating "game design" into programming/non-programming topics.

Comment: and what about game design type questions?

Comment: @LoopyWolf: As mentioned, "game design" can refer to many things. If the topic involves programming of some kind, then StackOverflow is an appropriate place to ask the question. Otherwise, your question should be posted elsewhere (see the two links I put in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Video Game questions aren't allowed on SU, but questions about MAKING games are fair game on SO - there's nothing game-specific about the programming used in games.

Game questions aren't allowed here because that would bring forth "Hey, I'm stuck on world 1-1 of mario, how do I jump?", and that's not why we're here. We're here for real questions not answered by GameFAQs or any other forum on the 'nets :P

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Stack Overflow-type site, but [gamedev.net](https://gamedev.net) is a specialized site for the purpose.